# Append List not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor, list, append

Trying to create a list of well counts. In the code below, wellCntList only contains the current county count and not a list of ALL the counts. Sure I'm missing something simple.

```
for cname in countyList:
    whereclause = "{} = '{}'".format("COUNTY", cname)
    wellCnt = 0
    wellCntList = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Wells_Intersect_Layer, "COUNTY", whereclause) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            wellCnt = wellCnt + 1
        wellCntList.append(wellCnt)
    print wellCntList
```

Comment: Please tag with the arcgis version you're using.

Comment: This definitely isn't GIS specific... This is a general programming problem.

Comment: @jpmc26 GIS and programming go hand-in-hand. This question in particular is on-topic as it refers to `arcpy` cursors.

Answer (score 7):

Try placing the `wellCntList` list outside of the `for` loop. Otherwise, each iteration is writing over the results of the previous one--ultimately leaving only the last iteration's results.

```
wellCntList = []

for cname in countyList:
    whereclause = "{} = '{}'".format("COUNTY", cname)
    wellCnt = 0
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Wells_Intersect_Layer, "COUNTY", whereclause) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            wellCnt = wellCnt + 1
        wellCntList.append(wellCnt)
    print wellCntList
```

---

However, for a more efficient and simple approach, I would use a dictionary via the Python [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module. For example, here I have a feature class with wells in 4 different counties ["A", "B", "C", "D"].

```
import arcpy
from collections import Counter

fc = r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\wells'

# Create a dict of well counts by county 
n = Counter(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "county"))
print n
```

---

The results:

```
>>> n
Counter({u'B': 30, u'C': 28, u'A': 20, u'D': 7})
```

Comment: Doesnt the append have to be in the for loop since the wellCnt is reset to 0 for each county?

Change wellCntList.append(wellCnt) to wellCntList = wellCntList.append(wellCnt)

Comment: @Ken Kirkeby, it's not clear what you're saying. No, you don't need to say "wellCntList = wellCntList.append (wellCnt)"; it won't make a difference. It looks to me like Aaron's indentation is correct, if you want wellCntList to be a lost of well counts by county. Of course, a dictionary would be a more efficient way to manage this, since you would only need to iterate through the records once.

Comment: @KenKirkeby This should yield a list along the lines of: `[12, 23, 45, ...]`. Are you trying to get a count of wells within each county? Why not use `arcpy.GetCount_management()`?

Comment: @Aaron  Not sure how to format arcpy.GetCount_management().  Do I need to create a feature layer first or is there a when to use it with the search cursor?

Comment: @KenKirkeby I added an example that should be better than the get count method.

Comment: @Aaron & etal. Thanks for all the assistance today. Five weeks does not a python programmer make.